# How to loop through a list in Python using range()

Tags: python, c

I don't know how to convert this loop in C to Python. Thanks in advance

I tried to convert

```
for(i=start, i<=end, i++)
   printf(ids[i])
```

to:

```
for x in range(start, end, ids):
   print(x)
```

But range requires integer values and ids is a list of strings.

I tried casting ids as integers but it says

> "ValueError: invalid literal for int()"

I need the values in ids to stay as characters because there are some letters in it.

Comment: `for x in range(start, stop+1, 1): print(ids[x])`  this article may be helpful: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

Answer (score 1):

```py
for id in ids:
    print(id)
```

will print all ids in the list, you can always set a break statement if you don't want all of them

```py
for id in ids:
    if count > start:
        print(id)

    count += 1

    if count >= end:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the strings

```
for id in ids:
    print(id)
```

If you need access to the index

```
for i in range(len(ids)):
    print(ids[i])
```

If you need access to the index and only want to loop until `end` (if 'end' is an integer)

```
for i in range(end):
    print(ids[i])
```